# CSS not working in Chrome web browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

As the title suggests I have a webpage and I tested it out in Google Chrome and the CSS did not work. I then went back and checked that I had linked the CSS file to the HTML one properly and I had. I then tried opening it in the Firefox web browser and it worked. Can anyone tell my why it is not working in Chrome but is working in Firefox?

The CSS file:

```
    #news {
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
#newsp {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#thankyou {
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}
#websiteul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#websitelist {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: We need more details. What is in the CSS file? Maybe you're using some Firefox-specific CSS rules which the Chrome engine would ignore.

Comment: @doldt I added in the css file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything special... When you open the developer console in Chrome, and inspect a DOM element which is supposed to have some CSS style (right click, inspect element), can you see CSS rules appearing on the right side?

Comment: can you create JSFiddle, for better understanding of your code?

Comment: @Javy According to your css I think margin-top seems doesn't work in chrome. To work in chrome use "-webkit-margin-before" style.

Comment: What do you mean "CSS not working.." - what part of it is not working? Do you use a css reset file?

Comment: None of the CSS is working at all. It's like it doesn't exist.

Comment: And just now I tried it and it worked! I didn't try anything different though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the animation but here is an animation for example:

```
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: white;}
   50% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
@keyframes {
    0% {background: white;}
   50% {background: white;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="first-child"></div>
```

If you want to make the animation work in chrome you should use `-webkit-animation` and if you want to make it work in firefox you should use `-moz-animation` like in the code